# Combine table data with historical table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to combine data from a table with a history table to form one result set as the data is captured differently in the two tables. Both tables have different criteria as below;

One query is 
select * from [RM-JOB] where [RM-JOB].[RECHARGE-TENANT] = 1

History table is

Select * from [RM-STAGE-HISTORY] where [STAGE-MAP] = 'RERQ'

The history table may have multiple entries for [STAGE-MAP] = 'RERQ' so I want the most recent.

Below is the query I have attempted.

```
select * from [RM-JOB] where [RM-JOB].[RECHARGE-TENANT] = 1 or [JOB-NO] in (


select [RM-JOB].[JOB-NO], [RM_STAGES].DESCRIPTION CurrentStatus, CSTAGE.DESCRIPTION CurrentStage, * from [RM-JOB] 
inner join (select [RM-STAGE-HISTORY].[JOB-NO], [RM-STAGE-HISTORY].[STAGE-CODE] from [RM-STAGE-HISTORY]  
where [STAGE-MAP] = 'RERQ' group by [JOB-NO],[RM-STAGE-HISTORY].[STAGE-CODE]) as StageMap on [RM-JOB].[JOB-NO] = StageMap.[JOB-NO]
inner join  [RM_STAGES] on [RM_STAGES].[STAGE-CODE] = [RM-JOB].[JOB-STATUS]
inner join [RM_STAGES] CSTAGE on CSTAGE.[STAGE-CODE] = StageMap.[STAGE-CODE]
inner join [IH-LOCATION] on [IH-LOCATION].[PLACE-REF] = [RM-JOB].[PLACE-REF]
inner join [CO-PLACE] on [CO-PLACE].[PLACE-REF] = [IH-LOCATION].[PLACE-REF]
```

The history table example is;

```
JOB-NO  STAGE-DATE  STAGE-TIME  STAGE-CODE  USER-ID MEMO    STAGE-MAP   USER-DATE   USER-TIME   STAGE-HIST-NUMBER
10128570    00:00.0 15:53:08    31  TMWSERVICE  Ticket No: 2    TMAC    00:00.0 15:53:19    1304576
10128570    00:00.0 15:53:16    34  TMWSERVICE  Ticket No: 2    TMST    00:00.0 15:53:21    1304577
10128570    00:00.0 15:54:22    52  TMWSERVICE  Ticket No: 2    RERQ    00:00.0 15:54:24    1304607
10128570    00:00.0 15:56:14    31  TMWSERVICE  Ticket No: 2    TMAC    00:00.0 15:56:24    1304646
```

and the normal table example is;

```
JOB-NO  PMT-METHOD  CURRENT-STAGE-CODE  JOB-STATUS  CLIENT-CODE CONTRACTOR  INITIAL-PRIORITY    LATEST-PRIORITY TRADE-CODE  PLACE-REF
10128570        95  93  HSG VIVID01 R   R   CR  OB6236001
```

The STAGE-HIST-NUMBER can be used for the maximum record.

Any advise is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show some data from both of the tables and what is your expected output?

Comment: Define most recent? Is there a date column or some other way to know the order? Posting table definitions and sample data would help considerably. Your attempt isn't working because you have bunch of columns in that subquery.

Comment: Please ensure you are doing inner-joins on key/foreign-key combinations, or things that work like them, if possible.  You may also want to consider a 'union' operation if the data is truly 'historical'

Comment: There is a reference number that I will use to identify the most recent stage with 'RERQ'.

Comment: The expected output is columns from the normal table.